# highlight certain words in the data frame Pandas HTML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to highlight certain words in the data frame. My codes are given below, the problem I am having is that it highlights only the first words from the "selected_ text" such an economy in this case, and not able to highlight other words even though they are present in the text. How can we change it in a way to highlight all words if present in the text?  Second, currently, I get only one words under the "existing" column. Can we get more than one word if they are present in the column "body_text"? and highlight them as well.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, Markdown, Latex, HTML
df =pd.read_csv("/content/df_eup.csv")
df.head(1)
```

[image]

```
df['body_text'].isnull().sum()
df.dropna(subset=['body_text'], inplace=True)
list_exist = []
selected_words=["economy", "recession", "unemployment", "depression","inflation", "covid19","virus"," bank"]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    word = selected_words[0]
    i = 0
    while (word not in row['body_text'] and i < 7 ):
        
        i +=1
        word = selected_words[i]
    if i<7:
        list_exist.append(selected_words[i])
    else:
        list_exist.append("not_exist")
df["existing"]=list_exist

def highlight_selected_text(row):
    text = row["body_text"]
    selected_text = ["economy", "recession", "unemployment", "depression","inflation", "covid19","virus","bank"]
    ext = row["existing"]

    color = {
        "economy": "red",
        "recession": "red",
        "unemployment": "red",
        "depression": "red",
        "inflation": "red",
        "covid19": "red",
        "virus" : "red",
        "bank": "red",
        "not_exist": "black"
        
    }[ext]

    highlighted = f'<span style="color: {color}; font-weight: bold">{ext}</span>'
    
    
    
    return text.replace(selected_text[0] or selected_text[1] or selected_text[2] or selected_text[3] or selected_text[4]or selected_text[5]or selected_text[6]or selected_text[7], highlighted)
df["highlighted"] = df.apply(highlight_selected_text, axis=1)


display(HTML(df.sample(30).to_html(escape=False)))
```

Sample output for the selection of more than words (For the second part of the question)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to retrieve dict value inside of f string:

```
def highlight_selected_text(row):
    text = row["body_text"]
    ext = row["existing"]
    color = {
        "economy": "red",
        "recession": "red",
        "unemployment": "red",
        "depression": "red",
        "inflation": "red",
        "covid19": "red",
        "virus" : "red",
        "bank": "red",
        "not_exist": "black"
    }

    for k, v in color.items():
        text = text.replace(k, f'<span style="color: {v}; font-weight: bold">{k}</span>')

    return text
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated but now getting this error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, Alexandra, I updated but it did not solve the problem of highlighting

Comment: Oh, try also to replace `return text.replace(selected_text[0] or selected_text[1] or selected_text[2] or selected_text[3] or selected_text[4]or selected_text[5]or selected_text[6]or selected_text[7], highlighted)` with `return text.replace(ext, highlighted)`

Comment: Thank you so much !! It worked. The first issue of highlighting is solved. Can you please help me with the second one? I want to select more than words under the column of "existing" if present in the text. Currently, I get only one word.

Comment: Could you give an example of result you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks once again! The articles in the "body_text" column can have words like, "economy", recession", "unemployment,  at the same time. I want if we can find them under the column "existing" and color them also. Currently, I am able to select one word from slected_text.

Comment: I have now added the sample output for the second part of the question.

Comment: Updated answer to iterate over dict and replace all present keys